# Wagtail search on empty query should return all data

Tags: elasticsearch, wagtail

I am using wagtail's get_search_backend.search to fetch data.
If the query string provided is empty, the use case for us is to return all the data.
Is there a way to achieve it?

Comment: Please add what you tried so far and -if applicable- a code sample and possible error codes so we can help you. Take a look [here for how to ask a better question on SO](https://developer.apple.com/support/compare-memberships/)

Comment: You could to a check on the query string before calling search. If empty just return Page.objects.all() - simple but should do what you want.